# Inflating only a specific action bar menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an action bar menu defined in my main activity. Now, one of the fragments I am using in that activity has its own action bar menu but when I click on the menu option, I get both the fragment's as well as the activity's menu items. How to ensure that only that fragment's menu item is displayed?

My java code for that fragment is:

```
public class ProfileD extends Fragment {

TextView tv_named, tv_genderd, tv_cfd, tv_aged, tv_biod, tv_statusd;
ImageView imageView_dp;

public ProfileD() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_d, container, false);

    tv_named = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_named);
    tv_genderd = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_genderd);
    tv_cfd= (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cfd);
    tv_aged = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_aged);
    tv_biod = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_biod);

    tv_statusd = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_statusd);

    imageView_dp = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_dp);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.profile_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.edit_profile) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),PersonalDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra("Edit",1);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity = (AppCompatActivity)getActivity();
    ActionBar actionBar = appCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Profile");
}
}
```

The xml file for the menu is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/edit_profile"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Edit"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I am posting it here so if anyone else is facing the same issue, they can benefit from this:

I created a static menu object and stored the activity's action bar menu in that object. I then called that object from my fragment and cleared it thereby clearing the activity's menu and leaving me with the fragment's menu

Here is the updated java code for the fragment

```
public class ProfileD extends Fragment {

TextView tv_named, tv_genderd, tv_cfd, tv_aged, tv_biod, tv_statusd;
ImageView imageView_dp;

public ProfileD() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_d, container, false);

    tv_named = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_named);
    tv_genderd = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_genderd);
    tv_cfd= (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cfd);
    tv_aged = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_aged);
    tv_biod = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_biod);

    tv_statusd = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_statusd);

    imageView_dp = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_dp);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    HomePage.menu_home.clear();

    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.profile_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.edit_profile) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),PersonalDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra("Edit",1);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity = (AppCompatActivity)getActivity();
    ActionBar actionBar = appCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Profile");
}
}
```